# Changing owner directly from cp

Tags: unix

At a final test in college, one of the subjects was : " Find a way to copy file /etc/sudoers in home of user "student". The resulted file has to be owned by "student". There are not allowed permission modifications on the source or destination file. "

I've tried everything but couldn't find a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being `student`, you can paste the file into your directory:

```
cat /etc/sudoers > /home/student/your_sudo
```

The file `your_sudo` will be created having `your_user` as owner. Note that you might need to use `sudo cat /etc/sudoers`, because this file can just have 770 permissions.

Comment: But for that you need to have administrative account!

Comment: Oh my God! I lost my time like half an hour on this question, thinking what I could use along with "cp" to make this work. It was so simple...